# Symfony 4 custom form type

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am trying to use a custom type form but I cannot render it (No errors at all, just an empty dropdown). The custom type is:

```
class RuleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
           'choices' => [
               '1' => 'Regle',
               '2' => 'Scenario'
           ],
        ]);
    }



    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }


}
```

and it is used in:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name',        TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'long')))
        ->add('ruleType',    RuleType::class)
        ->add('isActive',    CheckboxType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('iconName',    Image::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('action',        EntityType::class, array('class' => 'App\Entity\Upv6\Actions', 'choice_label' => 'internalName'))
        ->add('rule',        TextareaType::class, array('required' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'editor')))
        ->add('comment',    TextareaType::class, array('required' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'comments')))
        ;
}
```

and the template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'monForm'},'action': path('iot6_SmartItBundle_RulesManager_Add') }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_label(form.name, 'msg.name'|trans) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.name) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_errors(form.name) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>{{ form_label(form.ruleType, 'msg.type'|trans) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.ruleType) }}</td>
            <td>{{ form_errors(form.ruleType) }}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: What errors or result do you get?

Comment: No errors at all, just an empty dropdown @PaulDixon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
```

should be

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
```

My guess is you're looking at some pre-2.7 sample code, as `setDefaultOptions` was [deprecated](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates) then. You can find the [latest docs for custom form types here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

Comment: Not really a guess :) I'm actually surprised your original ran at all, as I assumed OptionsResolverInterface was removed in v3. Glad it works for you now!

Comment: no exception at all for using OptionsResolverInterface